# OpenCV Visualizing the Whole Process of TemplateMatching

Tags: opencv, visualization, template-matching

I am fresh on OPENCV combined with C++. I have a question as following.
If we would like to visualize the whole process when doing template matching, is that possible? If it does, which OPENCV's functions should I refer?
Basically, how should we do in order to visualize a template image(smaller scale) is moving on(user defined method) background image(bigger scale)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use template matching function there is no way to visualise the process as it goes. You can visualise the resulting image, with grey levels associated to how well the template is fitted at each location in the original image.
If you really want to visualise the process, you have to do it yourself: implement convolution, write the loop and call `imshow` at every iteration.